# Синонимы сова печаль

Tags: синонимы

Является ли слово "расстройство" синонимом слова "печаль"?

Answer (score 3):

Если и является, то очень далеким. Во-первых, "расстройство" в этом значении используется разве что в книжном стиле, а "печаль" слово скорее поэтическое.  Во-вторых, печаль может быть вызвана не только расстройством. "Печаль моя светла" - Вы можете представить себе замену на "расстройство"? Наконец, даже в значении, которое можно признать частичным синонимом (см. "во-первых"), "расстройство" при всем том шире. "Он расстроился от неприятных известий, но не опечалился, а мобилизовался" - мне кажется вполне понятно. Тут правда, глаголы, не существительные, но это только подчеркивает разницу.

Очень близкий синоним - грусть.

Answer (score 1):

Человек "расстроился" - это значит, что его вывели из равновесия с помощью какого-то негатива. Сначала он даже не может сам определить, какое чувство станет следствием ситуации. Мне кажется, наиболее близким синонимом является "огорчился". Он уже потом будет печалиться, грустить - или не будет.

Answer (score 1):

Самый подходящий вариант - грусть. Возможно, устаревшее - кручина.